# Mocha: How to add codeblock(tests as function/string) instead of mocha.addFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am using Mocha programmatically and it is explained in detail in the [link](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) about how to add test files but I have the tests saved in db as strings. Is there a way I can directly add them as strings/functions instead of creating temporary buffers and adding them as files?

```
//write my tests stored as strings into filesystem
fs.writeFile("tempdir", myTest, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return;
    } 
}); 

var mocha = new Mocha;

// Then, you need to use the method "addFile" on the mocha
// object for each file.

// Here is an example:
fs.readdirSync('tempdir').filter(function(file){
    // Only keep the .js files
    return file.substr(-3) === '.js';

}).forEach(function(file){
    // Use the method "addFile" to add the file to mocha
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join('some/dir', file)
    );

//remove the test created in tempdir
```